# How does my comparator method violate its general contract?

Tags: java, java-7, comparator

### Third-Party Packages

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
```

### My Comparator

```java
public static Comparator<Task> TASK_PRIORITY = new Comparator<Task>() {
    public int compare(Task task1, Task task2) {
        if (task1 == null && task2 == null) return 0;
        if (task1 == null) return +1; //null last
        if (task2 == null) return -1; //null last

        // Only consider retries after a task is retried 5+ times
        if (task1.getRetries() >= 5 || task2.getRetries() >= 5) {
            // Primary sort: retry count (ascending)
            int retriesCompare = Integer.compare(task1.getRetries(), task2.getRetries());
            if (retriesCompare != 0) return retriesCompare;
        }

        // Secondary sort: creation time (ascending, null first)
        int creationCompare = compareTimeNullFirst(task1.getCreationTime(), task2.getCreationTime());
        if (creationCompare != 0) return creationCompare;

        // Tertiary sort: load time (ascending, null last)
        int loadCompare = compareTimeNullLast(task1.getLoadTime(), task2.getLoadTime());
        if (loadCompare != 0) return loadCompare;

        return 0;
    }
};

private static int compareTimeNullLast(DateTime time1, DateTime time2) {
    if (time1 == null && time2 == null) return 0;
    if (time1 == null) return +1;
    if (time2 == null) return -1;
    if (time1.isBefore(time2) return -1;
    if (time1.isAfter(time2)) return +1;
    return 0;
}

private static int compareTimeNullFirst(DateTime time1, DateTime time2) {
    if (time1 == null && time2 == null) return 0;
    if (time1 == null) return -1;
    if (time2 == null) return +1;
    if (time1.isBefore(time2) return -1;
    if (time1.isAfter(time2)) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

### Using My Comparator

```java
//tasks is a List<Task>
Collections.sort(tasks, TASK_PRIORITY);
```

### My Problem

I sometimes get an `IllegalArgumentException` for `Comparison method violates its general contract!`. I can consistently get this Exception thrown with live data running long enough, but I'm not sure how to fix the actual cause of the problem.

### My Question

What is wrong with my comparator? (Specifically, which part of the contract am I violating?) How do I fix it without covering up the Exception?

### Notes

- I'm using Java 7 and cannot upgrade without a major rewrite.
- I could possibly cover-up the Exception by setting `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` to `true`, but that is not a desirable solution.
- I tried to create tests to randomly generate data and verify each of the [contract conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)). I wasn't able to get the exception to be thrown.
- I tried removing the condition around the retry comparison, but I still eventually got the Exception.
- This line throws the exception: `Collections.sort(tasks, TASK_PRIORITY);`

Comment: It means your a.equals(b) is not the same as b.equals(a)

Comment: Are these tasks being updated and retried in some other thread while the sort is running? In other words, could their retry counts change during the sort? Or could other data change during the sort? Could a pair of tasks compare differently at different times during the course of a single sort operation?

Comment: @Ryan That's not a strict requirement as per the wording `It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals."`

Comment: Could you specify which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @David I use `ImmutableSet.copyOf` to copy the list before sorting, and I do that under a read lock in `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: @Nicktar Added to the Notes.

Comment: Copying the set does not copy the set elements.  So the two sets contain the same objects.  If the objects are mutated while you are sorting the collection ... then ... boom!

Comment: @Stephen Interesting... What if I create a new list with `Lists.newArrayList`, lock, add the elements to the new list, unlock, then sort the new list?

Comment: Does the lock stop other threads mutating the objects in the old list?   If not, maybe you should be deep-copying the list; i.e. creating copies / clones of the elements of the list.

Comment: @StephenC I think you've solved my problem. I only recently added the retry counting, and modifying it was not done under lock. Thanks! If you want to answer the question, I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us start at the beginning.  My reading of your code is that the logic of your Comparator is sound.  (I would have avoided having null `Task` and `DateTime` values, but that is not relevant to your problem.)

The other thing that can cause this exception is if the `compare` method is giving inconsistent results because the `Task` objects are changing.  Indeed, it looks like it is semantically meaningful for (at least) the retry counts to change.  If there is another thread that is changing `Task` the fields that can effect the ordering ... while the current thread is sorting ... that could the `IllegalArgumentException`.

(Part of the comparison contract is that pairwise ordering does not change while you are sorting the collection.)

You then say this:

> I use `ImmutableSet.copyOf` to copy the list before sorting, and I do that under a read lock in `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock`.

Copying a collection doesn't make copies of the elements of the collection.  It is a shallow copy.  So you will end up with two collections that contain the same objects.  If the other thread mutates any of the objects (e.g. by increasing retry counts), that could change the ordering of objects.

The locking makes sure that you have consistent copy, but that's not what the problem is.

What is the solution?  I can think of a couple:

1. You could lock something to block all updates to the collections AND the element objects while you copy and sort.
2. You could deep-copy the collect; i.e. create a new collection containing copies of the elements of the original collection.
3. You could create light-weight objects that contain a snapshots of the fields of the `Task` objects that are relevant to sorting; e.g.

   ```
   public class Key implements Comparable<Key> {
       private int retries;
       private DateTime creation;
       private DateTime load;
       private Task task;

       public Key(Task task) {
           this.task = task;
           this.retries = task.getRetryCount();
           ...
       }

       public int compareTo(Key other) {
           // compare using retries, creation, load
       }
   }
   ```

   This has the potential advantages that you are copying less information, and you can go from the sorted collection of `Key` objects to the original `Task` objects.

Note all of these alternatives are slower than what you are currently doing.  I don't think there is a way to avoid this.